How to properly implement a ZoneSpecification(fork: ) handler in Dart
When I try to implement a fork override for ZoneSpecifications like this:
runZoned(
() {
  runZoned(() {
    print('in zone');
  });
},
zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
  fork: (self, parent, zone, specification, zoneValues) {
    print('forked!');
    return zone.fork(specification: specification, zoneValues: zoneValues);
  },
),

);
I only get this:

forked! (x7990)
forked!
Unhandled exception:
Stack Overflow
#0      _print (dart:_builtin:29:1)
...
#7993   _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

On the code I read that only the RootZone contains the enter zone, so I'm lost on how to accomplish the task.

The call to zone.fork in your handler fork and the nested runZoned seem to cause a recursive call to the fork handler and eventually a stackoverflow.
The example below uses the fork handler of the ZoneDelegate parent to create the fork and adds some zoneValues to help identify the zones:
import 'dart:async';

int id = 0;

void main(List<String> args) {
  runZoned(
      () {
        print(' ... Now in zone: ${Zone.current[#id]}');
        print('     parent zone: ${Zone.current.parent}');

        runZoned(
          () {
            print('     ... Now in zone: ${Zone.current[#id]}');
            print('         parent zone: ${Zone.current.parent![#id]}');
          },
          zoneValues: {#id: ++id},
        );
      },
      zoneValues: {#id: ++id},
      zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(fork: (
        self,
        parent,
        zone,
        specification,
        zoneValues,
      ) {
        print('     Forking zone with id: ${zone[#id]}');
        // Custom fork handler increments forked zone id by 100.
        return parent.fork(
          zone,
          specification,
          {#id: (zoneValues![#id] as int) + 100}, 
        );
      }));
}


The console output is listed below:
$ dart zone_example.dart 
... Now in zone: 1
     parent zone: Instance of '_RootZone'
     Forking zone with id: 1
     ... Now in zone: 102
         parent zone: 1


Thank you so much, Dan! Excellent answer btw
